# Imagick::steganoImage usage

Tags: php, imagick

I'm trying to understand how steganoImage command in PHP works but the documentation is no avail in PHP.net (I mean not complete)

Can somebody explain to me how to use that command or is it more suitable to run pure ImageMagick to take its full functionality?

Thanks in advance

*update
Sorry for not give links
Here's the links from PHP site http://php.net/manual/en/imagick.steganoimage.php